# Microsoft Sync framework source code

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

Does anyone know if the MS Sync Framework source code is available  and how to obtain it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source itself is Microsoft's IP. In other words, it's proprietary and not open sourced. They have an SDK to allow developers to use the framework. Here's the [Microsoft Sync SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ee6af141-79d0-4351-a4a0-ea89bb29dcf5&displaylang=en).